# php regex - Replace all @usernames with link in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am implimenting a timeline system on my website where users can mention others users in their timeline using **@username** like twitter.

I want to convert **@username** to link and point it to their profile

My string :

```
$timeline="@fred-ii 's posts on @stackoverflow are intresting.";
```

I am using the following code to replace @username with url :

```
echo preg_replace("/@([^\s]+)/i","<a href='http://example.com/$1'>@$1</a>",$timeline);
```

it works, the problem is that it matchs spaces also

this string

```
"@fred-ii 's posts on@stackoverflow";
```

There is no space between **on** and **@stackoverflow** ,I want to exclude it,

so i updated my regex

```
/\s+@([^\s]+)/
```

it worked but it didnot match the first part of my string (username **@fred-ii** ) .I think regex engine is looking for space|s at the start of string.

What do I need to change in my pattern to match all @usernames ?

```
$timeline="@fred-ii 's posts on @stackoverflow are intresting.";
```

Comment: So you want to match the space in the username, but don't have a space in the link?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [lookbehind negative assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/(?<!\w)@([^\s]+)/
```

The `(?<!\w)` tells the Regex engine to match `@([^\s]+)` only if it's not preceded by a word `\w`. It will work in the example you gave, perhaps you will have to tweak it as you go.

Example code:

```
$pattern = "/(?<!\w)@([^\s]+)/";
$subject = "@fred-ii 's posts on @stackoverflow are interesting. @fred-ii 's posts on@stackoverflow";

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER );

foreach($matches as $item)
{
    echo $item[1] . "<br/>";
}
```

Produces this output:

```
fred-ii
stackoverflow
fred-ii
```

See it in [action](https://regex101.com/r/jU8mK5/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lookbehind assertion:

```
/(?<=\s|^)@\S+/
```

`(?<=\s|^)` makes sure there is whitespace or line start before `@`.

**Code:**

```
php> $s = "@fred-ii 's posts on@stackoverflow";

php> echo preg_replace('/(?<=\s|^)@\S+/', "<a href='http://example.com/$0'>$0</a>", $s);
<a href='http://example.com/fred-ii'>@fred-ii</a> 's posts on@stackoverflow
```

Comment: Anubhava your answer is korrect, it gives the korrect output. but what if I don't use **lookbehind** forexample the pattern 

**/(\s+|^)@([^\s]+)/** also works, is it correct to use it or always with lookbehind. please guide me.

Comment: Yes you can also use: `/(?:\s|^)@([^\s]+)/` with captured group. Lookbehind gives you an option of not using any captured group at all using: **`preg_replace('/(?<=\s|^)@\S+/', "<a href='http://example.com/$0'>$0</a>", $s);`**

Comment: [Thank you](https://eval.in/473806) so much for the explaination Anubhava , I learned alot about LookBehind from your answer and comment. I really appriciate it.

Comment: Anubhava Do you know how to match a string in Shell based wildcard expresion? sorry for adding an unrelated comment, I'ma remove it soon.

Comment: Try: **`s="@fred-ii 's posts on@stackoverflow"; sed -r 's~(^|[[:blank:]])(@[^[:blank:]]+)~\1<a href="http://example.com/\2">\2</a>~' <<< "$s"`**