# PHP convert string starting with @ to user profile URL

Tags: php

I have PHP code which shows post text. Sometimes this post text content contains user mentions like @[2] where 2 is the serial number of the row for the mentioned user in the user table in my database. Suppose this user has username @mark.

I want to replace this mention code @[2] with a user profile link, for example `<a href="https://example.com/mark">@mark</a>`

Like take value 2 from @[2] string. This value is a variable
Find respected row in user table in database for
Show username and user profile link instead of @[2].

Comment: Why would anyone write `@[2]` instead of `@name`? How would users know the database-internal index no? Is this question about linkifying those placeholders, or about doing the database lookups (=too broad)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php regex - Replace all @usernames with link in a string](//stackoverflow.com/q/33844826) / [Regular expression to convert usernames into links like Twitter does](//stackoverflow.com/q/2705769)

Comment: I have purchased a script which shows mentions as @[2] instead of @name. so i want to implement this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php regex - Replace all @usernames with link in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33844826/php-regex-replace-all-usernames-with-link-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

For the string replacement trick, you'd usually use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback).
The weirdo `@[2]` placeholder can be matched with a regex like:

```
/@\[(\d+)\]/
# ↑   ↑   ↑
#@ [ num  ]
```

And then you do your link mapping in the callback:

```
$texty = preg_replace_callback(
     "/@\[(\d+)\]/",
     function($m) {
         return "<a href='/profile?id=$m[1]'>" . user_id_to_name($m[1]) . "</a>";
     }
     $texty
);
```

Obviously with the appropriate id→name lookup function for your database.